# Fragments, The method Fragment1() is undefined for the type MainActivity I would like explaining please

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been following a tutorial on fragments just to get a bit of exposure to them, I've followed the tutorial to the end and Eclipse is throwing the error `"The method Fragment1() is undefined for the type MainActivity"` now I'm not sure if is to do with the `Import.R.Android.*` problem I was having earlier and its now not referring to `Fragment1.class?` Or has something been missed on the tutorial initializing the Fragment?

As I understand from 
    public void Onclick(View v) {

```
    Fragment newFragment;

    if (v == button1) {
        newFragment = Fragment1();
    }else if (v == button2) {
        newFragment = Fragment2();
    }else if (v == button3) {
        newFragment = Fragment3();
    }else {
        newFragment = StartFragment();
    }

}
```

It replaces the placeholder `Fragment(newFragment)` with a fragment based off which button was pressed? Or am I missing something that should obvious? Thank you for any help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Onclick"
            android:text="Frag1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Onclick"
            android:text="Frag2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="Frag3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

TLDR: I know its because the fragment is not defined but since I was following a tutorial I don't know yet how to define one.

The Android developer guides do not help with this particular case as they seem to be implementing them in a different way to this tutorial.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `newFragment = new Fragment1();`?

Comment: Like Luksprog said, instantiating objects needs the `new` keyword. And don't compare v with `==` use the id instead.

Comment: Thank you both very much too, is this 
'if (findViewById(R.id.button1) == button1) {
   newFragment = new Fragment1();
  }else if (findViewById(R.id.button2) == button2) {
   newFragment = new Fragment2();
  }else if (findViewById(R.id.button3) == button3) {
   newFragment = new Fragment3();
  }else {
   newFragment = new StartFragment();
  }'
 what you mean I should do?

Comment: @Pheonix2105 `if (v.getId() == R.id.myButton)` Optimally you use a switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest finding a nice book or website on how to code in Java before attempting to learn the Android framework, as it seems you have some problems with Java classes and some basic Java syntax.

To Java, `newFragment = Fragment1();` is a method call. It has a method name (`Fragment`), and and is passing in no arguments.

To instantiate an object (such as a Fragment), you need to use the new keyword. For example, `Fragment myFragment = new Fragment1();`.

Furthermore, it isn't clear from your code snippets, but you must have classes defined of types `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, etc. These should extend the `Fragment` class.

I highly recommend following the [Android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), as the guide you are following doesn't seem to be helping you much, and the official guide provides very nice examples of how Google says you should organize and code your application.

Comment: The Android Developers Guide on Fragments is quite frankly daunting, which is why I wanted a tutorial that shows me what the mass of code is referring to. I guessed it was along them lines but simply assumed the tutorial creator was correct, I have Fragment1.class, etc I just didn't include them and they do extend the Fragment class, I'm afraid I'm one of them people where reading only gets you so far. Thank you very much :).